# Kivy throws error: virtual keyboard not allowed, single mode, not docked, and doesn't open Keyboard for TextInput Widget

Tags: python, keyboard, kivy

I've even tried adding the line `Config.set('kivy', 'keyboard_mode', 'auto')` and tried `Config.set('kivy', 'keyboard_mode', 'systemandmulti')` with no success, still getting that message `[Window      ] virtual keyboard not allowed, single mode, not docked`.

The effect of this behavior is that I can't even open the keyboard when the TextInput field is pressed.

How do I fix this bug?

Answer (score 2):

before you load kivy.app load kivy.config first

```html
from kivy.config import Config
Config.set('kivy','keyboard_mode','systemanddock')
from kivy.app import App
```

Answer (score 0):

May be you forget to call your mainApp class.

if **name** == "**main**":

```
MyApp().run()
```